# MaterializeCSS: Buttons do not vertically align (but input-fields do) inside footer

Tags: html, css, materialize

If I use `valign-wrapper` with a `.btn` in a Materialize.css `.page-footer`, it does not vertically align. e.g., the following html:

```
<footer class="page-footer">
    <div class="valign-wrapper row col 12" id="rowContainer">
        <div class="col s12">
            <button class="btn btn-block waves-effect waves-light light-blue" type="submit" name="action">btn1</button>
        </div>
</footer>
```

produces:

[image: Footer with button not vertically aligned]

Note: in my stylesheet, I have:

```
.btn-block
{
    width: 100%;
}
```

To make buttons with the `.btn-block` class fit to the width of their container.

If I replace the button with an `.input-field`, everything works as expected (i.e. it is vertically aligned in the footer). e.g.:

```
<footer class="page-footer">
    <div class="valign-wrapper row col 12" id="rowContainer">
        <div class="input-field col s12">
            <input placeholder="Input1" type="text" class="center-align">
        </div>
</footer>
```

produces:

[image: Properly aligned <code>.input-field</code>]

Why is this happening and how can I vertically align my button? It is my understanding that `.valign-wrapper` should do this for me.

Note that in my actual application, I am add several buttons to the footer; that is why I am using the `.row` class with a specified number of columns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay I see. I've had issues vertically aligning certain things within divs in Materialize too. The work around can be tedious but try something like this.

HTML:

```
<footer class="page-footer">
  <div class="valign-wrapper row col 12" id="rowContainer">
     <div class="col s12">
       <button class="btn btn-block waves-effect waves-light light-blue" 
         type="submit" name="action">btn1</button>
    </div>
</footer>
```

CSS:

```
.valign-wrapper {
height:100px;
padding-top: 70px;
border-style: solid; /*just used to show footer height*/
border-color: black; /*just used to show footer height*/
}

.btn-block {
width: 100%;
}
```

You'll probably have to tweak the

```
    padding-top: 70px;
```

line to fit your footer.

Here's the codepen:

https://codepen.io/controllz/pen/mdyLRXQ

I added the border in CSS just to show the footer height. Remove that when you get it right.
Hope this helps.

Comment: I played around a bit with what you sent and for some reason simply adding: `.valign-wrapper
{
height: 70px;
}
`

did the trick. I'm assuming it's because this is the height of the footer itself.

Comment: Very cool. I really love Materialize CSS but little things like this make me wonder: Is it still in its' infancy? or was it purposely made like this so I can control everything myself? Anyways, a pleasure to help and great luck to you.

Comment: Yeah I'm really enjoying using it and thank you for the help!

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you are trying to vertically align your buttons? You can add a line break after each instance within the footer.

```
<footer class="page-footer">
<div class="valign-wrapper row col 12" id="rowContainer">
    <div class="col s12">
        <button class="btn btn-block waves-effect waves-light light-blue" 
type="submit" name="action">btn1</button>
      <br>
       <button class="btn btn-block waves-effect waves-light light-blue" 
type="submit" name="action">btn1</button>
      <br>
       <button class="btn btn-block waves-effect waves-light light-blue" 
type="submit" name="action">btn1</button>
    </div>
</footer>
```

Comment: Sorry I should have been more clear in my OP: I'm not trying to stack them vertically; I'm trying to align them in one row which is centered within the footer. The issue isn't that they are next to each other; the issue is that they are being placed at the top of the footer rather than the vertical center.